# How to apply a custom template to a code-first database in Azure?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I'm creating a microservices architecture.

Each service needs its own database, so I've created an SQL Server resource in my Azure's Resource Group.

But the databases are created code-first by the services when they are deployed.

In Azure, it results with a newly created database attached to my SQL Server, and so in my Resource Group. Exactly what I want.

But unfortunately, the database configuration is the raw default of Azure, with 32GB and costs me a lot more money than it should.

I don't need more than 100mb per database and I can even pick the "serverless" Computer tier option to pay lesser.

So I've created a template of database and now I'm trying to assign it as the default template used by the SQL Server resource whenever a microservice creates a new database.

Is it even possible ?

Comment: I understood that you created your sever database upfront? IMHO you should also created databases at this moment and you services should be responsible for creating structure.

Comment: Yes I think this is what i will end up doing. I wanted my services to be completely independents but I can at least create the database and let the service creates the tables.